# insert custom fields to the top of drupal 7 form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
$form = drupal_get_form('geography');
$form['input_latitude'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('Search address'), 
  '#weight' => -10,
);
```

I can insert a new custom field in Drupal 7 using the code above. However, it will appear at the very bottom of the geography form. How can i place it at the very top instead? Note: weight => -10 does not work.

Comment: Try starting with `#weight => 0' or no weight at all.

Comment: Print the form you get to see what weights other fields have.

Comment: Alter form with hook : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x